# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry

Tags: android, duplicates

Please help, I can't build the application.  I updated Android studio and my builds failed. Here is the full error:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v7/util/MessageThreadUtil$SyncQueueItem.class

and here are my dependencies:
`dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile project(':cheetah-mobile-3.4.7')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'
}`

build.gradle:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.bitcoinxpress"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

Comment: it is about conflict  dependencies. I think you have conflict your main dependencies with `cheetah-mobile-3.4.7` dependencies. check and remove what duplicates

Comment: Thanks, how would I check for duplicates?

Comment: You can try the answer below first.

Comment: That did not correct my issue.

Comment: try to remove each compile and run (comments all codes relative with that compile, if necessary) and see which ones make confict then we can check solution next time

Answer (score 1):

You can view which dependencies conflict each other by typing this into the console:

```
    ./gradlew app:dependencies
```

I recommend starting your search from the library that is specified from the exception. Everything with an asterisk (*) in front of it signifies that it is conflicting with another library.  The very first occurence of this library will not have a * and thats the one you know to keep. All of the other imports should be excluded like so:

```
    implementation('com.some.library:1.2.3') {
    exclude(group: "name.of.library.before.colon", module: "name-after-colon")
}
```

Since you are adding an exclude to this library you must surround the name of the lib with paranthesis as shown above.